Crashes while trying to create an instance of a child class
I have _Object which is a parent class and i have _Button which is a child class. Here's my terrifying code:
class _Object {
protected:
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    const char* image_path;
    static uint64_t count; /* 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 objects ought to be enough for anybody */
    uint_least32_t group;
    static std::set<int_fast64_t> z_order_set;
    int_fast64_t z_order;
    int64_t x;
    int64_t y;
    uint8_t alpha;
    uint16_t rot;
    float scale;
    static int_fast64_t uniquify_z_order(int_fast64_t& z_order) {
        if (z_order >= 0) {
            while (z_order_set.find(z_order) != z_order_set.end()) {
                z_order++;
                if (z_order == INT_FAST64_MAX) {
                    goto EXCEPTION;
                }
            }
        } else {
            while (z_order_set.find(z_order) != z_order_set.end()) {
                z_order--;
                if (z_order == INT_FAST64_MIN) {
                    goto EXCEPTION;
                }
            }
        }
        return z_order;
EXCEPTION:
        z_order = 0;
        return 0;
    }
public:
    _Object() = delete;
    _Object(SDL_Renderer* rend, int_fast64_t z_order, const char* image, int x, int y) {
        _constructor(rend, z_order, image, x, y, ((uint8_t)255), ((uint16_t)0), 100.0f);
    }
    _Object(SDL_Renderer* rend, int_fast64_t z_order, const char* image, int x, int y, uint8_t alpha, uint16_t rot, float scale) {
        _constructor(rend, z_order, image, x, y, alpha, rot, scale);
    }
    _Object(SDL_Renderer* rend, _Object* obj) {
        _constructor(rend, obj->z_order, obj->image_path, obj->x, obj->y, obj->alpha, obj->rot, obj->scale);
    }
    ~_Object() {
        SDL_DestroyTexture(this->texture);
    }
    /* Constructor */
    void _constructor(SDL_Renderer* rend, int_fast64_t z_order, const char* image_path, int x, int y, uint8_t alpha, uint16_t rot, float scale) {
        if (z_order != 0) {
            if (z_order_set.find(z_order) != z_order_set.end()) {
                stacktrace(module::warning, "z_order (%lld) is already in use. New unique z_order: %lld", z_order, uniquify_z_order(z_order));
                if (z_order == 0) {
                    stacktrace(module::error, "No free z_order left. Object discarded.");
                    this->z_order_set.erase(z_order);
                    throw OUT_OF_Z_ORDER;
                }
            }
            this->z_order_set.insert(z_order);
            this->z_order = z_order;
        } else {
            stacktrace(module::error, "Attempted to use zero as a z_order (reserved for player). Object discarded.");
            throw OUT_OF_Z_ORDER;
        }
        this->texture = IMG_LoadTexture(rend, image_path);
        if (!this->texture) {
            stacktrace(module::error, "Couldn't load \"%s\". Object discarded.", image_path);
            this->z_order_set.erase(z_order);
            throw;
        }
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->alpha = alpha;
        this->rot = rot;
        this->scale = scale;
    }
    /* Methods */
    SDL_Texture* get_texture(void) const {
        return this->texture;
    }
    std::pair<int64_t, int64_t> get_position(void) const {
        return {this->x, this->y};
    }
    void move_to(int64_t x, int64_t y) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
    void move_from(int x, int y) {
        this->x += x;
        this->y += y;
    }
};

uint64_t _Object::count = 0;
std::set<int_fast64_t> _Object::z_order_set;

class _Button : public _Object {
    const char* image = path::img::menu_button; //the path is valid, i double-checked
public:
    _Button() = delete;
    _Button(SDL_Renderer* rend, int_fast64_t z_order, int x, int y)
        : _Object(rend, z_order, image, x, y) {}
    _Button(SDL_Renderer* rend, int_fast64_t z_order, int x, int y, uint8_t alpha, uint16_t rot, float scale)
        : _Object(rend, z_order, image, x, y, alpha, rot, scale) {}
    ~_Button() = default;
    bool was_clicked(int mouse_x, int mouse_y) {
        int txtrw, txtrh;
        SDL_QueryTexture(this->get_texture(), NULL, NULL, &txtrw, &txtrh);
        auto [xpos, ypos] = this->get_position();
        return (mouse_x >= xpos && mouse_x <= xpos + txtrw && mouse_y >= ypos && mouse_y <= ypos + txtrh);
    }
};


The problem is that i if i try to create an instance of _Object it works perfectly fine:
_Object* my_object = new _Object(rend, 69, "whatever.png", 0, 0); //fine

But when i'm trying to create an instance of _Button the program crashes:
_Button* my_button = new _Button(rend, 420, 0, 0); //crash

I also noticed that copy construtor doesn't work, too:
_Object* my_object = new _Object(rend, 69, "whatever.png", 0, 0); //fine
_Object* my_object_2 = new _Object(rend, my_object); //crash

I would like to understand what could be causing these issues because i have no idea. Perhaps i'm doing something wrong.
I tried asking chatgpt for a solution. Time wasted.

Your debugger will tell you exactly what causes the crash.  Asider: identifiers starting from an underscore and a capital letter are reserved, using them is undefined behaviour. Another aside: new and raw pointers have been out of fashion for a good decade.

Also try to avoid new/delete, use std::make_unique. And const char* image_path; no use std::string for this.  And really really stop using GOTO. Whoever taught you C++ didn't do a good job. So before continue (making a game), take a step back and learn some more C++ basics (e.g. learncpp.com). And then learn about abstract baseclasses, dependency injection and unit testability of your code (games tend to get large and thus really need some design up-front)

Obligatory warning. Names beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the compiler and should not be used in user code.

I don't see any reason for the crash, but the code is terrifying. Try not to rely on so many pointers.

One easy thing you can do is that since calling a copy constructor or assignment operator on your object is not a good idea you should delete those methods _Object(const _Object&) = delete; and _Object& operator=(const _Object&) = delete;. If that throws up any compiler errors, then you have found a bug.

Dupe: C++ Inheritance and Initialisation order

It is about order of initialization. The base class is initialized first, and the derived class' path variable only later. That gives the base class an uninitialized pointer.
The standard says:

In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the
following order:
— First, and only for the constructor of the
most derived class (6.7.2), virtual base classes are initialized in
the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the
directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the
order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class
base-specifier-list.
— Then, direct base classes are
initialized in declaration order as they appear in the
base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
— Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order
they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the
order of the mem-initializers).
— Finally, the
compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.
[Note 6 : The
declaration order is mandated to ensure that base and member
subobjects are destroyed in the reverse order of initialization. —end
note]


Presumably making Button::image static would fix this problem.

I passed path::img::menu_button directly to the constructor and it worked.
class _Button : public _Object {
public:
    _Button(SDL_Renderer* rend, int_fast64_t z_order, int x, int y)
        : _Object(rend, z_order, path::img::menu_button, x, y) {}
/* it works! */

